# Show that $B^{\circ}= \bigcup ( x\in E , d(x,B^c)\geq \frac{1}{n} ).$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset E$.
$\text { Show that } \stackrel{\circ}{B}=\bigcup\left\{x \in E, \quad d\left(x,  B^{ c} \right) \geq \frac{1}{n}\right\} ; \quad \forall B \varsubsetneqq E \text {. }$ 
for $\implies$ 
since $ \stackrel{\circ}{B}$ is open then  $\exists \epsilon >0$ $\forall x\in B$ $B(x,\epsilon) \subset B$ $\implies$ $B(x,\epsilon) ∩  B^c=\varnothing$ let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ so  $d(x, y)\geq \frac{1}{n}$ $\forall y \in B^c$. Hence $ \stackrel{\circ}{B} \ \subset\bigcup\left\{x \in E, \quad d\left(x,  B^{ c} \right) \geq \frac{1}{n}\right\} ; \quad \forall B \varsubsetneqq E $ .
But I couldn't show the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $d(x,B^{c}) \geq \frac  1n$. If $d(x,y) <\frac 1 {2n}$ then $d(x,B^{c}) \leq d(y,B^{c})+d(x,y) <d(y,B^{c})+\frac 1 {2n}$ which gives $d(y,B^{c}) >\frac 1 {2n} >0$. This implies that $y \in B$. Hence, $B(x,\frac  1{2n})$ is contained in $B$ proving that $x$ is an interior point of $B$.

Comment: I got it thank you!!